# Time Out Expired - Moving Data from managed Intance to DataWarehouse AZure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

We have huge data to be moved betwwen managed instance and DataWarehouse.We are using a
bulk insert to Move the data.

Issue:
Time Out Expired - Moving Data from managed Intance to DataWarehouse AZure Data Factory.

Attached the screenhots for the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThLBR.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the timeout in the sink tab of the copy activity.

[image]

By default it is 2 hours, you can modify that if the insert is taking longer than that. The format is HH:mm:ss (timespan). Doc about this here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server#sql-server-as-a-sink

Aditionally, you can increase the number of DIU (data integration units) from the Settings tab of the copy activity. Your image shows 4 DIU being used, try adding more to that.

Hope this helped!